# How to combine 2 columns with different names to fill the nulls of the first with the values of the second?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, null

i have this df:

```
           country  customer_id   invoice   price   stream_id   times_viewed    year    month   day total_price StreamID    TimesViewed
0   United Kingdom  13085.0        489434    6.95       85048           12.0    2017       11   28          NaN      NaN            NaN
1   United Kingdom  NaN            489597    8.65       22130            1.0    2017       11   28          NaN      NaN            NaN
2   United Kingdom  NaN            489597    1.70       22132            6.0    2017       11   28          NaN     NaN              NaN
3   United Kingdom  NaN            489597    1.70       22133            4.0    2017       11   28          NaN     NaN             NaN
4   United Kingdom  NaN            489597    0.87       22134            1.0    2017       11   28          NaN     NaN             NaN
```

The columns `stream_id` and `StreamID` are in fact the same thing. The df i have is much larger and it was created by chunks. The problem came that when reading those chunks, some of them had the column name as `stream_id` and some others had `StreamID` instead, so when putting all the chunks together using `pd.concat` the final result look like this.

What i would like to do is to fill the null values of `StreamID` with the values of `stream_id` when this last one is not null. I'm not sure if this is the right approach or there is a more efficient way of solving this problem.

The same problem occurred with the `times_viewed` and the `TimesViewed` columns, so the same solution would apply for this one too.

I tried using `np.where` like this:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['StreamID'].isnull(), df['stream_id'], df['StreamID'])
```

But i'm not sure if this is right or if there is a better way to do it. Could someone please help me solve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think what would be better is to rename your columns before you concat to avoid this problem, other than that `np.where` or `df.loc` to fill the null values then drop the duplicate columns.

Comment: Hi @Datanovice. Yeah i know, but i have composed this df from a lot of separate json files and it would be a pain to find out which files have which column names. Is for that i'm seeking for another way to solve this. How would you do it with `np.where` or `df.iloc`?

Comment: `are the columns ordered, just rename them according to order, or use `index=False` in `pd.concat` to concat along the top axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it solved by progressively renaming the wrong column names after checking they exist, then added each df created from each file to a temporary list that got concatenated in the end, giving the final result:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = sorted(glob.glob(os.getcwd() + "/data_dir/*.json"))

df_list = []

for i in files:

    temp_df = pd.read_json(i)

    if 'StreamID' in temp_df.columns or 'total_price' in temp_df.columns or 'TimesViewed' in temp_df.columns:

        temp_df.rename(columns = {'StreamID': 'stream_id', 'total_price': 'price', 'TimesViewed': 'times_viewed'}, inplace = True)

    df_list.append(temp_df)

df = pd.concat(df_list, axis = 0)
```

It totally solved the issue of duplicated columns with wrong names. Hopefully, this will help someone.